# Where I can find AVM2 disassembler (or dump tool)?

Tags: disassembly, avm2

Greetings
I found this nice answer:
[How are methods found in AVM2 bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089291/how-are-methods-found-in-avm2-bytecode)
See number 3.
May anyone help me?
What is the tool used to produce abcFile dump?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWFWire inspector looks good answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

you can find it here http://www.yogda.com/

Comment: First of all - thank you for advice.Yogda is not perfect. It shows the nice GUI and readable assembler codes. But I need dump of data structures for SWF file sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool is called "abcdump". I found [some instructions](http://zetafleet.com/blog/compiling-the-latest-abcdump) on how to compile it.

Comment: I had not success with running it. It fails on mac os.